# jQuery Nano Scroll -Issue

Tags: jquery, html

I have used jQuery Nano Scroll plugin in my html page.

Issue: The scrollpane does not visible. when i inspect the div using chrome, then scrollpane has been displaying.

Any solution?

My code:

```
     <style type="text/css">
      .gt-scroll-prime{
        height: 150px;
        }
       </style>

     <div class="gt-scroll-prime cs-scroller">
            <div class="cs-scroller-content">

            </div>  
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Pls check the link
http://jsfiddle.net/z4krnu1n/2/

Comment: Nothing is showing up in the results section.

Comment: Now check: http://jsfiddle.net/z4krnu1n/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check working link

[FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/z4krnu1n/5/)

I guess the reason it is now working might be that you have changed the `nano` class names into your custom names. If you do that, you might need to change the references in the `nanoscroller.css`as well. I have tried to put the default class names in your fiddle and it worked.